# LESS nested rule for selecting all except a pseudo element

Tags: css, css-selectors, less

I'm writing a LESS nested rule that at the moment looks like this:

```
.content {
     margin-bottom: 30px;
     &:last-child {
        margin-bottom: 0;
     }
}
```

But I want to do it with a not selector and not have to define the margin twice. I don't want to have to reset in the last-child-selector.

What I want to do is something like this:

```
.content {
   &:not(:last-child) {
        margin-bottom: 30px;
   }
}
```

Resulting CSS:

```
.content:not(:last-child) {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

But my syntax seems wrong, cause it's not working, no elements get a bottom margin of 30px.

I haven't used the not-selector before, so I'm a little uncertain about the syntax. Is it possible to do and if yes, how?

**How do I write a rule in LESS syntax that selects every child element of a particular div, except the last one?**

Comment: That's not a LESS rule, I want to write it LESS syntax and nested, but I didn't work anyway

Comment: Maybe this will work: `&:not(&:last-child)`, not sure though.

Comment: @MikaldL No, didn't work either

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, some terminology to clarify: selectors never match *pseudo-elements*. In your case, `:last-child` is a *pseudo-class*, not a pseudo-element.

A [pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#pseudo-classes) acts like a class selector or an ID selector or a type selector, in that all of them match *elements*, and they act directly on whichever element you attach them to. These are all known as [simple selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selector-syntax).  In fact, `:not()` itself is also a pseudo-class — which just happens to accept a simple selector as an argument, such as another pseudo-class.

A [pseudo-element](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#pseudo-elements) on the other hand is a separate concept from an element entirely. A pseudo-element is special in that it is not a simple selector, and therefore a selector will never actually match or apply styles to a pseudo-element unless you specify that pseudo-element.

Now, what the selector `.content:not(:last-child)` means is

> Select any element
>   that has a class `content`
>   and is not the last child of its parent.

But that's not what you're trying to do. You're trying to select all but the last child *of* `.content`, so you need to separate them with a combinator. The most appropriate one to use is, of course, the child combinator:

```
.content {
    > :not(:last-child) {
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
}
```

This will compile to:

```
.content > :not(:last-child) {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

## Clarification:

The [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:not) says:

> `:not(X)`: X must not contain another negation selector, or any pseudo-elements.

`:last-child` is a **pseudo-class**, not a **pseudo-element**, so  it should definitely work. Also, MDN is not wrong (as I suggested before).

See [W3C specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation):

> The negation pseudo-class, :not(X), is a functional notation taking a simple selector (excluding the negation pseudo-class itself) as an argument.

and what is actually a [simple selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#simple-selectors-dfn)?

> A simple selector is either a type selector, universal selector, attribute selector, class selector, ID selector, or **pseudo-class**.

## How to write it in LESS?

LESS way for it would be:

```
.content {
    :not(:last-child) {
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
}
```

All credits go to [user2915402](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2915402/user2915402), so if he edits his question to work with LESS and link to sources, I will delete mine.

Comment: it would work if `:last-child` wasn't an pseudo-class... in your case it is not possible. See my updated answer.

Comment: This is odd, you seem to be right, but @Nathan below has provided an example of where it actually works with a pseudo element. How can that be, then?

Comment: @seven-phases-max actually, it does. I just tried it in Chrome and it works. However, it doesn't work in IE (surprise)

Comment: @stinaq, sorry I deleted my comment to make an update before I saw your reply. Indeed it works in Chrome and FF. In fact this all is not that simple as MDN referenced above says. see http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation

Comment: W3C also states that: "Note also that since pseudo-elements are not simple selectors, they are not a valid argument to `:not()`." However the `:last-child` is *not* a pseudo-element :) it is a pseudo-class (pseudo-elements are `::before`, `::after` etc. - [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#pseudo-elements)).

Comment: Yeah, just noticed that. Now I believe I finally have the fully correct version of my answer. A lot of lessons learned!

Comment: @stinaq: If it doesn't work in IE, then you're testing in a really old version. If you need to support really old versions of IE, you'll have to forget about using `:not()` and `:last-child` and most other new CSS3 pseudo-classes.

Comment: Now that I tried it works perfectly in IE 9+, awesome. Thanks so much for all the lessons

Answer (score 2):

Try the below.

```
.content {
   &:not(:last-child) {
        margin-bottom: 30px;
   }
}
```

The resultant output would be..

```
.content:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, that seems to be the exact same code as I have written above, or am I missing something?

Comment: The same code with change in class from `.bdo` to `.content` - @stinaq

Comment: You can paste it **[Here](http://www.webtoolkitonline.com/less-to-css.html)** and verify the same. - @stinaq

Comment: Ah, the bdo-part was just a typo from me, I fixed it in the question in an edit!

Comment: Yes, but under the compiler that I provided above, it shows that there is an error on line 2 and 5. - @stinaq

Answer (score 2):

This is how it can be done using LESS:

```
.content__item {
  &:not(:last-child) {
    margin-bottom: 1.5rem;
  }
}
```

for

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="content__item">This has margin bottom</div>
    <div class="content__item">This has margin bottom too</div>
    <div class="content__item">This not</div>
</div>
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/VcEFu/1/

Comment: The code sample is misleading, but your fiddle actually works.

Comment: This works but targets the children you're styling. OP wanted to target the parent element (`.content`, not `.content__item`)